# Reading ejabberd.yml module parameter fails

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I have a Ejabberd module for pushing notifications in case the recipient of a message is offline. In principle, it works reasonably well. One problem is that the URL to which I push the notification is hard-coded in the module. Intuitively this should be configurable in the `ejabberd.yml` conf file.

The relevant snippet in my `ejabberd.yml` looks like this

```
modules:
  mod_fcm_fork:
    post_url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/notification/push/"
```

The problem is that I cannot access that value inside my module, at least not in the way I can find on the Web:

```
push_notification(From, To, Packet) ->
  URL = gen_mod:get_module_opt(global, ?MODULE, post_url, []),
  %URL = gen_mod:get_module_opt(To#jid.lserver, ?MODULE, post_url, []),
  ?INFO_MSG("mod_fcm_fork -> push_notification: ~p~n",[URL]),
  ...
```

This command throws the following warning (not even an error):

```
[warning] <0.5453.0>@ejabberd_config:prepare_opt_val:806 incorrect value '"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/notification/push/"' of option 'post_url', using 'undefined' as fallback
```

So it kind of finds / sees the value. Any way the `?INFO_MSG` prints and `undefined`:

```
2017-01-26 20:16:09.019 [info] <0.5453.0>@mod_fcm_fork:push_notification:52 mod_fcm_fork -> push_notification: undefined
```

Interestingly, the following works nicely:

```
start(Host, _Opts) ->
  URL = proplists:get_value(post_url, _Opts),
  ?INFO_MSG("HTTP client started ~p~n", [URL]),
```

But in `push_notification` I don't have access to `_Opts` which in turn is called by a hook. So how can I get the `post_url` value in the method `push_notification`?

Comment: try gen_mod:get_module_opt(global,?MODULE,post_url,fun(X) -> X end, all).

Comment: @MarynaKrasnova, thanks! I works just fine now. You're my life saver at the moment. Where can I find that stuff? Everything I find using Google seems to be obsolete even if I limit the results to the last year. Nothing works out of the box for me. Now Ejabberd won't start when I'm trying to enable 'mod_mam', even when following the official docs. It's a bit frustrating frankly I will try for myself for another 1-2h and the post another question here. Again, your help is very much appreciated. You might want to make a proper answer so I can accept it.

Comment: actually I don't know ejabberd enough well and same problems with docs, so somethimes I just using find code to get example, like 
$cd src $grep -r "gen_mod:get_module_opt" or smthk like this, it is bad stuff but works somethimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gen_mod:get_module_opt(global,?MODULE,post_url,fun(X) -> X end, all)
```